# How to use "next_in_line" instead of "super"

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

This is a "How to" question rather than a "Should I ?" To a resonable extent, I do understand the limitations of such a replacement.

In his excellent talk on [Super considered super!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo), Raymond Hettinger's mentions that he considers "super" is a bad name for "super" and that we should think of it more as "next in line".
Like scores of others who would have listened to this talk, I too feel it makes sense.

So, In my own code, I was thinking if I can use a different name/handle whenever I want to call "*next in line*", instead of using `super`. 
I am thinking of using the handle : "***next_in_line***", as it is the intuitive name for the replacement !

I understand the potential conflicts that could happen if this name is used in any other imported packages. But I am not concerned about that during my exploratory/learning time in Python.

So, my question is: How should I go about achieving this in a central place ?

Taking the example from Raymond's related [blog post](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

```py
class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'Setting key {key} to {value}')
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

I want to be able to do this instead :

```py
class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'Setting key {key} to {value}')
        next_in_line().__setitem__(key, value)
```

**Edit1**:

While am looking for doing this in ONE place and not in each module, even the following resulted in error:

```py
next_in_line = super

class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'Setting key {key} to {value}')
        next_in_line().__setitem__(key, value)

ld = LoggingDict()
ld[1] = 'a'
```

Output:

```py
Setting key 1 to a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pyth/logging_dict.py", line 9, in <module>
    ld[1] = 'a'
  File "D:/pyth/logging_dict.py", line 6, in __setitem__
    next_in_line().__setitem__(key, value)
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

Comment: Just put `next_in_line = super` where appropriate? (top of module/before you need to use it)

Comment: I did try that...sorry I didnt mention it before...but got an error. Have updated my question with the outcome now.. may be i didnt try it the right way ?

Comment: Ahhh of course... ignore that then... chalk it up to a *brain burp* :p

Comment: Isn't it easier to just learn that `super` means _next in line_? I mean, if you ever share your code with someone else, anything other than that will be utterly confusing.

Comment: when this question came up in my mind, i saw it as an opportunity to learn from the experts... as I felt the answer would touch upon concepts I am not aware of... so, no I wouldnt do this in a project that involves others ...

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: don't do that!** The `super` keyword is part of the Python language. If you don't like it, fork the language and try to convince other programmers to follow you. Otherwise your code will be unintelligible to everyone except you (and perhaps even to you).

Now you've been warned... you can use the explicit form of `super`:

```
next_in_line = super

class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'Setting key {key} to {value}')
        next_in_line(LoggingDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

Or you can hack the `__globals__` attribute of the function in a decorator:

```
def next_in_line(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def nel(t=type(self), o=self):
            return super(t, o)
        func.__globals__["next_in_line"] = nel
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner


class LoggingDict(dict):
    @next_in_line
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'Setting key {key} to {value}')
        next_in_line().__setitem__(key, value)
```

But again, don't do that.

Comment: That definitely doesnt seem simple or maintainable...so I will heed your advice (if no better way shows up)...